# Easiest way to replace a specific word in text files (htm format) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to replace an "XXX" word in some text files (.htm if it makes a difference). I guess I would need to parse the text files into DOM and find the "XXX" word? What is the difference between [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) and [Htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2)?

Edit: Example, thanks to @Thijs:

```
const
  textIn = document.getElementById('text-input'),
  textOut = document.getElementById('output');

textOut.value= textIn.value.replace(/salami/g, 'CHOCOLATE');
```

Yes, this is what I want, but how to load the text files to `document`. The text files are provided, I would rather not to heavily modify them. [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) and [Htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2) came up when I searched. Am I correct that with templates, I will have to construct my own text files?

Comment: you can use anything you like. If you are trying to create templates, use something like handlebars.

Comment: Can you show us EXACTLY what you're trying to replace?  It makes a big difference if you can accomplish what you want with text searches rather than actually parsing the whole DOM.  Whether that is feasible depends upon exactly what you're actually trying to do.  Some types of text replacement can be done incrementally with a stream transformation.

Comment: I agree with shams.kool's comment that perhaps what you want to use is a template engine that already does replacement or insertion into HTML templates to generate a finished HTML file.  There are dozens of template engines that work with node.js such as handlebars, EJS, jade, pug.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace a word inside a piece of text, you can use replace on the input string. The example below replaces `salami` with `CHOCOLATE`. You need a regex with the `g` modifier or else only the first occurrence is replaced.

```js
const
  textIn = document.getElementById('text-input'),
  textOut = document.getElementById('output');
  
textOut.value= textIn.value.replace(/salami/g, 'CHOCOLATE');
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0 10vw;
}

textarea {
  height: 40vh;
  margin: 0 10vw 5vh;
  width: 80vw;
}
```

```html
<p>BEFORE:</p>
<textarea id="text-input">
Landjaeger cupim doner tongue salami burgdoggen alcatra boudin kevin. T-bone pork loin pastrami pancetta boudin, frankfurter salami drumstick burgdoggen tail hamburger shoulder short loin bresaola. Bacon spare ribs turducken, rump ribeye jowl pork loin chicken salami. Pig rump chicken shank filet mignon ham hock turducken. Sausage short loin prosciutto ribeye burgdoggen picanha salami swine frankfurter jowl spare ribs meatloaf. Andouille shoulder spare ribs ham. Tongue venison swine spare ribs.

Burgdoggen frankfurter landjaeger bacon, bresaola t-bone turducken shankle prosciutto ground round flank. Salami tail ham cow short ribs pork drumstick shoulder meatball. Beef bresaola short ribs spare ribs capicola boudin, fatback t-bone rump ball tip leberkas pig short loin hamburger. Shank boudin meatball salami bacon. Kielbasa short ribs pork belly ribeye jerky strip steak venison short loin meatball pork chop. Fatback meatball swine hamburger doner tail burgdoggen prosciutto shoulder meatloaf spare ribs short loin porchetta.
</textarea>

<p>AFTER:</p>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```